# JGit: How to fix NoRemoteRepositoryException while creating Git Repository and pushing it to GitHub?

Tags: java, jgit

Using JGit, I want to create a NEW repository and push it to GitHub. I am getting NoRemoteRepositoryException. Please help. What am I missing in my code?

```
private void createNewRepository(Task task, String path) {
  File directory = new File(path);
  try {
    Git git = Git.init().setDirectory(directory).call();
    git.add().addFilepattern( "readme.txt" ).call();
    git.commit().setMessage( "Create readme file" ).call();

    RemoteAddCommand remoteAddCommand = git.remoteAdd();
    remoteAddCommand.setName("origin");
    remoteAddCommand.setUri(new URIish(task.getVcUrl()));
    remoteAddCommand.call();

    CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(task.getVcUsername(), task.getVcPassword());   
     git.push().setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).
        setRemote("origin").setPushAll().setForce(true).call();
  } catch (GitAPIException ex) {
    logger.warn(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
    taskLogger.get().append(ex.getLocalizedMessage()).append("\n");
  } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

The error stacktrace is

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NoRemoteRepositoryException: 
    http://github.com/AAA/Orgtest_sd3: 
    https://github.com/AAA/Orgtest_sd3/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack not 
found
    at 
org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:520)
    at 
org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openPush(TransportHttp.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PushProcess.execute(PushProcess.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.push(Transport.java:1344)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PushCommand.call(PushCommand.java:169)
```

Comment: To with URL does `task.getVcUrl()` point to? Did you make sure that the URLs mentioned in the stacktrace actually exist?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann, task.getVcUrl() returns the URL of the new repository I would like to create on GitHub. Please help me correct my code logic.

Comment: You simply cannot create a new remote repository. Neither with JGit nor with native Git. You'll have to first create a repository on the remote host, then you can clone, fetch, and push from /to this repository.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann Thanks for the information . If you add an answer, I can close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a new remote repository from your local host, neither with JGit nor with native Git.

You'll have to first create a repository on the remote host, then you can clone, fetch, and push from/to this repository.

Comment: Thanks @RudigerHerrmann . Instead of JGit, I am now exploring REST APIs 
 - https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create .

Comment: i create the repository first  manually in my GitHub and then run my java code to see it uploads the files.. its not working.. it still contains throws the same error..